# Flutter Persistent Bottom App Bar to Display Text Only (no nav)

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomappbar

my two page Flutter app needs a persistent bottom app bar, just to display up to a few lines of text, no navigation. Also, this bottom section should not overlap any content; rather constrain it, like the top app bar.
suggestions appreciated. examples super appreciated.
thanks!

================@chunhunghan================
thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately bottom sheet is hiding content:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `bottomSheet` and wrap `AppBar` with `Container` set `kToolbarHeight`

```
bottomSheet: Container(
        height: kToolbarHeight,
        child: AppBar(
          title: Text("bottom sheet"),
        ),
      ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                  children:
                      List.generate(100, (i) => Text("line" + i.toString()))),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: Container(
        height: kToolbarHeight,
        child: AppBar(
          title: Text("bottom sheet"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

would suggest to go ahead and use the `bottomNavigationBar` like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new ListView(
         children: List.generate(100, (i) => Text("this is a line" + i.toString()))
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar:Text(
        "this is some info"
      ) 
    );
  }
```

In this example, you can see that all the items in the list are displayed and not hidden under the bottom app bar.